# how to set layout_margin for a view (not for a viewGroup) programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am facing issue when setting the `layout_margin` programatically for the dynamically created `ImageView` inside a `GridLayout`.
I have tried the below code :

---

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.idGridLayout);

    gridLayout.setColumnCount(10);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(10);


    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        ImageView tile1 = new ImageView();
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(100, 100);

        tile1.setLayoutParams(lp);
       lp.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4); ////not working some error
        tile1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 5));
        //tile1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aalien);
        //tile1.setBackgroundColor();
```

---

I have found a method `setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4)`, but by this I can set the margin only for a `ViewGroups` like `LinearLayout`/`GridLayout`/`RelativeLayout` etc.

But I want to set margin for the `ImageView` like I do in the `xml` by using the `android:layout_margin="5dp"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this for each `ImageView`

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

params.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4); // left, top, right, bottom

imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```